# Migrate xib file to Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib, autolayout

This should be an easy one, but surprisingly I could not find any information about it being or not being possible to do.

I have some .xib files created in older versions of Xcode/Interface Builder and I would like to use Xcode 4.4's new features but so far I've only been able to achieve this by deleting the older .xib files and creating new ones from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update the older xib files' development target. Select the xib file from the project navigator and open the file inspector. In the file inspector's Interface Builder Document section is a Development menu. Try updating the development target to Xcode 4.4 and see if that allows you to take advantage of the new Xcode 4.4 features.

If updating the development target doesn't work, you'll have to provide some more information about the problems you're having and the features you haven't been able to access.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what all the new Xcode features are. The one I was particularly after was the auto layout. Turns out it is a separate feature. Since my .xib file was created using a previous version of Xcode the feature was disabled by default. Just enabled it and bam!